# Display attributed text of UILabel in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

So I'm trying to get attributed text with various colors to display on a `UIView`. My variables are

`NSMutableAttributedString *myString`;

`UILabel *myLabel;`

`UIView *myView;`

First, I did the following in order to assign myLabel's attributedText to myString

```
[myLabel setAttributedText: myString];
```

Now I'm not entirely sure how to add `myLabel` to `myView` in order to make it so that the attributed text shows up. It seems that `UIView's` acknowledge `UILabel textfields` but not `attributedtextfields`

Comment: Are you using storyboards to setup the views or adding them programmatically [self addSubview:mylabel] ?

Comment: I'm adding them programmically.

Comment: What is the relationship in adding a label to view with attributed text setted in label?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes a difference for the view if you are adding a label with attributed string or regular string. You just addSubview:MyLabel
Check out the code bellow.

```
//setup the testview
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    [testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    //setup the label
    UILabel *txtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [txtLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    NSDictionary *attrib = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]};
    NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"test" attributes:attrib];
    txtLabel.attributedText = attribString;
    [testView addSubview:txtLabel]; //add the label to the testview
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to addSubview **BEFORE** applying attributedText to UILabel

```
let text = NSMutableAttributedString()
text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "AAA", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)]))
text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "bbb", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]))

let label = UILabel()

view.addSubview(label)

label.attributedText = text
label.sizeToFit()
```

if you move view.addSubview(label) after label.attributedText = text, this label will show same attributes for all text